# Best way to confirm two strings are valid JSON stringified representations of the same object

Tags: json, jestjs

I am writing tests to verify I am correctly computing my Hasura Claims in a Cognito preTokenGeneration Lambda.

Hasura needs me to pass a claim which is a stringified object like:

```
"https://hasura.io/jwt/claims":"{\"x-hasura-user-id-cognito-sub\":\"88d22e5d-939a-4c5f-a074-c906d9fadc9e\",\"x-hasura-default-role\":\"unregistered\",\"x-hasura-allowed-roles\":[\"unregistered\"],\"x-hasura-email\":\"me@mine.com\"}",
```

but because object members don't have an order, there can be several stringified representations of an object - the following are all valid stringified representations of the same object:

```js
const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

`{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`
`{"b":2, "c":3, "a":1}`
`{"c":3, "a":1, "b":2}`

Hence I currently parse it to an object and compare like this:

```
expect(JSON.parse(result['https://hasura.io/jwt/claims'])).toEqual({
  'x-hasura-user-id-cognito-sub': mockCognitoSub,
  'x-hasura-default-role': `unregistered`,
  'x-hasura-allowed-roles': `unregistered`,
  'x-hasura-email': mockEmails,
});
```

Is there a native Jest `expect` functionality I am unaware of where I can see if two strings are both valid stringified representations of the same object?

Comment: You can see the "native jest expect functionality" [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect) - you can [extend](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers) it but it's not built in.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native Jest method to that, and it seems that [`jest-extended`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers) doesn't have it as well.

So you can either have a function if you want to shorten and reuse:

```
expect(JSON.parse(result['https://hasura.io/jwt/claims'])).toEqual({
```

Or you can [extend Jest matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers) to create your own matcher, something like:

```
const { diff } = require("jest-diff");

function toMatchParsedObject(actual, matched) {
  const parsedActual = JSON.parse(actual);
  const passed = this.equals(parsedActual, matched);

  if (passed) {
    return {
      message: () =>
        `expected ${this.utils.printReceived(
          actual
        )} not to be ${this.utils.printExpected(matched)}
        ${diff(parsedActual, matched)}`,
      pass: true,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      message: () =>
        `expected ${this.utils.printReceived(
          diff(parsedActual, matched)
        )} to be ${this.utils.printExpected(matched)}
        ${diff(parsedActual, matched)}`,
      pass: false,
    };
  }
}

expect.extend({
  toMatchParsedObject,
});

it("works", () => {
  expect('{"b":2,"a":1,"c":3}').toMatchParsedObject({
    b: 2,
    // a: 1,
    c: 3,
  });
});
```

---

Update:

You might want to consider [jest-json-matchers](https://github.com/debugmaster/jest-json-matchers) library that extends Jest matchers with methods like: `toMatchJSON` and `expect.jsonContaining(object)`